# How to create dconf site setting file to disable all Super Key assignments

Tags: gnome, dconf, shortcut-keys, vncviewer

The site https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators indicates that there is a method to install a single file to override the defaults provided with GNOME in a proper manner from an administrator's point of view.

In particular, I want to set up a `/etc/dconf/db/site.d/00_site_settings` file so that all value entries in the path org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings have all references to "Super" removed. [i.e. the Windows/Super_key values deleted]

It would solve update issues where the value portion of each pair gets overwritten by an update or a console login - thereby causing VNC clients major problems with their "s" and "h" keys after "Super" reappears...

(I manually searched with dconf editor and think this might handle it. Please comment if you can think of an automated, scripted method... Thanks...)

```
# /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/10-nosuperkey-settings
#
# This file is a site config file to disable "Super/Windows" key bindings
# so that vnc clients can operate properly.
#
# use "dconf update" to incorporate into db the first time
#

[org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings]
maximize='' 
minimize='' 
move-to-workspace-down=['<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']
move-to-workspace-up=['<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
panel-main-menu=['<Alt>F1'] 
switch-applications=['<Alt>Tab']
switch-group=['<Alt>Above_Tab'] 
switch-input-source=''
switch-input-source-backward='' 
switch-to-workspace-down=['<Control><Alt>Down']
switch-to-workspace-up=['<Control><Alt>Up']
unmaximize=['<Alt>F5']
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Just a note, some markup does not work/is buggy (html) `<br>` did not work correctly in your post so I edited it out. (You can just do a newline twice)